# Validating POPO's with Symfony2

Tags: validation, symfony

I am trying to validate parameters with Json-RPC. With Symfony2 validation I can do this:

```
$expense = new Expense;
$expense->setAmount(1);
$validator = $this->get('validator');
$errors = $validator->validate($expense);
```

But I do not want to manually specify each parameter with the `setFoo()` method. Is there anyway to bind the data similar to how the Symfony `Form` library works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is not possible with Symfony2. You will have to bind the data yourself. I created a bind method similar to this:

```
$params = array('amount' => 1);

foreach($params as $key => $value) {
    try {
        $path = new PropertyPath($key);
        $path->setValue($obj, $value);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        // parameter does not exist in POPO
    }
}
```

After you bind your parameters to the POPO object, you can validate it normally.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, `$errors = $validator->validate($user)` will do the job. See [using the validator service](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/validation.html#using-the-validator-service) documentation.